# Get distance travelled if the starting and ending point is the same in Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-directions-api

I'm working on Google Maps directions API.
I need to calculate the distance traveled between two points.
If the starting and ending point is same how can we calculate the distance traveled?

Can anyone help me or give some suggestions regarding this?

Comment: If starting and ending points are same then there must be some `waypoints` to calculate distance traveled.

Comment: ... or the distance is zero.

Comment: yes u are correct, the distance will be zero.. is there any way to calculate the distance, if my starting and ending points are same

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
public double Distance(LatLng StartP, LatLng EndP) {
        int Radius = 6371;// radius of earth in Km
        double lat1 = StartP.latitude;
        double lat2 = EndP.latitude;
        double lon1 = StartP.longitude;
        double lon2 = EndP.longitude;
        double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
        double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
        double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2)
                + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1))
                * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLon / 2)
                * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
        double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
        double valueResult = Radius * c;
        double km = valueResult / 1;
        DecimalFormat newFormat = new DecimalFormat("####");
        int kmInDec = Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(km));
        double meter = valueResult % 1000;
        int meterInDec = Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(meter));
        Log.i("Radius Value", "" + valueResult + "   KM  " + kmInDec
                + " Meter   " + meterInDec);

        return Radius * c;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but my starting and ending point will be same. In that case how this code will work out. In dLat and dLon the values will be 0 because my lat-long will be same

Comment: you mean you cover the distance and after that you reached your position where you start?

Comment: @NandhiniB just store starting latitude and longitude in variables like StartLat=somevalue and StartLong=somevalue and check in condition if startLat==EndLat&&StartLong==EndLong then not update End variables otherwise update EndLat and EndLong with somevalues hope you will understand if not then let me know Note somevalues are latitude and longitude values which you get by moving.

Comment: Yeah.. I got ur point.. I think it might work, I'll check it.. :) Thanks alot.

Comment: @NandhiniB if this solution works for you kindly upvote or mark as solution Thank you and Happy coding :)

Comment: @WaleedAsim we cannot compare latitude and longitude by equals because we cannot get same lat long even when we are in exact location.